# Считать матрицу из файла и записать отредактировав в новый файл через файловые потоки

Tags: c++, файлы, матрицы, потоки-данных

Задание:
Считать матрицу из файла и заменить все элементы, расположенные выше главной диагонали на нули. Результат вычисления с соответствующими комментариями записать в новый файл.

Делал через файловые показатели все работает, но нужно сделать файловыми потоками.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

#define SIZE 5
using namespace std;
// 2 спосіб використовуючи файлові потоки

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    ifstream lab5;
    lab5.open("SHMO-LR5.txt");
    if (!lab5.is_open())
    {
        printf("Файл не відкрився");
        exit(1);
    }

    int matrix[SIZE][SIZE];
    string temp;

    
    ofstream lab5_2;
    lab5_2.open("SHMO-LR5-2.txt");
    

     lab5_2 << "Матриця:\n";
     cout << "Матриця:\n";

     lab5.ignore(363);
     int i = 0, j = 0;
     while (!lab5.eof())
     {
    
      lab5 >> temp;
      if (i < j)
      
          matrix[i][j] = 0;
      else
        matrix[i][j] = stoi(temp);
      
      if (j < SIZE)
          j++;
      else
      {
          i++;
          j = 0;
      }
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
     {
         cout << '\n';
         lab5_2 << '\n';
         for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
         {
             lab5_2 << matrix[i][j] << '\t';
             cout << matrix[i][j] << '\t';
         }

     }

    lab5.close();
    lab5_2.close();
}
```

Файл:

```
 В:25
    1. Створити  квадратну  матрицю  розміром  5х5,  значення  елементів  якої заповнити за допомогою генератору випадкових чисел.
    Записати створену матрицю в файл для подальшої обробки.
    2. Зчитати матрицю з файлу й замінити всі елементи, що розташовані вище головної діагоналі на нулі. 
    3. Результат обчислення з відповідними коментарями записати в новий файл
    
      4 -1  7  8 14
     -9 11 18  2  7
     11  9  5 -9  2
      8-18 -8 -4  4
     12  0 10-11 16
```

Должно быть так:

```
Матриця:

  4   0   0   0   0 
 -9  11   0   0   0 
 11   9   5   0   0 
  8 -18  -8  -4   0 
 12   0  10 -11  16
```

А работает так:

```
Матриця:

-11 0   0   0   0   
-8  -3  0   0   0   
8   -12 -10 0   0   
5   15  0   4   0   
7   7   -858993460  -858993460  -858993460
```

Пробовал по-другому, но результат такой
Код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

#define SIZE 5
using namespace std;
// 2 спосіб використовуючи файлові потоки

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    //FILE* lab5 = fopen("SHMO-LR5.txt", "r");
    ifstream lab5;
    lab5.open("SHMO-LR5.txt");
    if (!lab5.is_open())
    {
        printf("Файл не відкрився");
        exit(1);
    }

    int matrix[SIZE][SIZE];
    //int temp;
    //char temp;
    //char temp[3];
    string temp;

    //FILE* lab5_2 = fopen("SHMO-LR5-2.txt", "w");
    ofstream lab5_2;
    lab5_2.open("SHMO-LR5-2.txt");
     //eek(lab5, 371, SEEK_SET);

    //fprintf(lab5_2, "Матриця:\n");
    //printf("Матриця:\n");
     lab5_2 << "Матриця:\n";
     cout << "Матриця:\n";

    // int ignorechar = 363;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        
            cout << '\n';
            lab5_2 << '\n';


            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            {
                //fscanf(lab5, "%d", &temp);
                //lab5.get(temp);

                lab5.ignore(363);

                while (!lab5.eof())
                    lab5 >> temp;
                //lab5.get(temp);
                //lab5.getline(temp);
                if (i < j)
                    matrix[i][j] = 0;
                else
                    matrix[i][j] = stoi(temp);
                //fprintf(lab5_2, "%3d ", matrix[i][j]);
                //printf("%3d ", matrix[i][j]);
                lab5_2 << matrix[i][j] << '\t';
                cout << matrix[i][j] << '\t';

                //ignorechar += temp.length() + 7;
            }
        
    }
    
    lab5.close();
    lab5_2.close();
}
```

И файл:

```
Матриця:

7   0   0   0   0   
7   7   0   0   0   
7   7   7   0   0   
7   7   7   7   0   
7   7   7   7   7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка в одном месте в цикле while `if(j < SIZE)`. Должно быть `if (j < SIZE-1)`. Из-за этого идет смещение по вводу цифр, т.к. Вы вводите не 5 столбцов, а 6. В итоге файл заканчивается раньше, чем вы заполнили матрицу.
Раз уж вы всё равно не обрабатываете ошибки ввода из файла (т.е. считается что в файле обязана быть матрица 5х5 без ошибок), тогда проще и нагляднее вводить матрицу из файла вот так:

```
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            lab5 >> temp;
            if (i < j)
              matrix[i][j] = 0;
            else
              matrix[i][j] = temp;
        }
```

Поскольку ввод и вывод у вас получается одинаковым, эти два шага можно объединить.

```
int temp;
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
   cout << '\n';
   lab5_2 << '\n';
   
   for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
   {
      lab5 >> temp;
      if (i < j)
         matrix[i][j] = 0;
      else
         matrix[i][j] = temp;

      lab5_2 << matrix[i][j] << '\t';
      cout << matrix[i][j] << '\t';
   }
}
```